# Problem JOINing three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I want to show all the `categories` and the `items` inside that each category which should store in `items_this_category`.

Note, I have created an associative table `item_categories` because one `item` can be listed in more than one category.

Here is a screen of `NaviCat` with structure and the `query`

[image]

Comment: Why do people downvote if you dont have answer???

Answer (score 2):

What you need can be achieved via a simple combination of two joins, Let's have a look at a sample query

```
Select < Fields as per your requirements >
From items i
Inner join item_categories ic On i.item_id=ic.item_id
Right outer join categories c On c.category_id=ic.category_id
Where <Any conditions you may have>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I like this answer because it exposes a flaw in the picture in the question. The arrow goes from `categories.category_id` to `item_categories.category_id`. For the picture to match this query, 2 things should be done for visual effect: 1) put the `items` table on the right and the `item_categories` table in the middle 2) put an arrow from `item_categories.item_id` to `items.item_id`. The query itself is essentially correct. If the picture was oriented the way I said, the query would be more obvious. +1 for Speedypoint.